# How to enable the Google Drive UI Integration?

Tags: google-cloud-console

A la here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/drive_sdk (plus your project name).

I've been trying for ages, but each time it returns a bad request.

```
{"code":4,"trackingId":"---","errorSpace":"core","status":400,"message":"bad request"}`.
```

Their support doesn't seem to be working.

I've tried grabbing the network request and running it through the cloud console, but that provides no further information.

Any ideas?

[image: -]

Comment: How is this related to the google-drive-api?

Answer (score 0):

After support told me that there was nothing that they could do I went back and tried again.

I initially had a leading period at the start of my default file extension, when I removed this it successfully submitted. It is worth noting that it says the extension is optional, but when I tried with no extension it failed as well. I guess it is not needed if you have a mime type, the form obviously has very basic and insufficient validation.

So in conclusion extension `.floop` bad, `floop` good.